# How to compute memory displacement in assembly?

Tags: memory, assembly

I've been working on yasm assembly language and I generated a listing file that contains the following. I need help understanding how the memory displacement is computed in the first column. Thanks in advance.

```
1                                %line 1+1 memory.asm
2                                [section .data]
3 00000000 04000000              a dd 4 
4 00000004 CDCC8C40              b dd 4.4 
5 00000008 00000000<rept>        c times 10 dd 0 
6 00000030 01000200              d dw 1, 2 
7 00000034 FB                    e db 0xfb
8 00000035 68656C6C6F20776F72-   f db "hello world", 0 
9 00000035 6C6400
```

Answer (score 1):

Assembler is producing bytes (machine code), starting at some start address (here `0`) and laying them next to each other. So first `a dd 4` produces 4 bytes of data `04 00 00 00`, thus memory at addresses 0, 1, 2 and 3 are filled up. Next free slot is at address 4. There goes `b dd 4.4`, again 4 bytes long. `c times 10 dd 0` is 40 bytes long, so 8+40 = 48 (0x30) => next free slot.